# Mutliple authorizations in a single browser in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

Is it possible to have other authorization in an iframe, which is already authorized from the same domain in ASP.NET MVC?

I mean after a user logged in with forms authentication mode, is it possible to have another forms authetication in iframe of the same browser. Both from same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is to store the authorization cookie and use Session, so it's not possible with the default behavior.

To do this you will need another way to store authorization data and track authorization

Comment: Could you please refer me where can I find such logic?

Comment: @Manikandhar you can use a token, which you will pass with every request (in header or query string). But why do you want this in the first place?

Comment: A requirement in our application, where an admin user will login as a client user from his account. I found a way to do this. Its true that browsers will have only single authorization, but a browser session can have different session objects in it. So I used it to meet our requirement by using a session object which holds the current admin logged in session object and overrides its authorization normally as other user and finally when things are done admin user can switch back through the session object that was created while overriding the authorization as client. A lots of security check...